# Talend open studio

Tags: linux, logging, configuration, talend

I am a beginner on talend open studio for data integration , and I work on a remote machine (linux server) with java 8 .
Whenever I start up Talend , it gives me an error saying : 
"An error has occured , see the log file " ( more détails in the photo ) 
So please any help !

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zk5q3.png)

Comment: How did you start Talend Studio?

Comment: Hello , Sorry for the delay , actually I solved the problem , and it was caused by Xming(For the graphical interface )  , so that's what i did : sudo cp /home/esb/.Xauthority /root (befor lanching Talnend ) that's all :)